# Convert SP 2013 Foundation into SP 2013 Server?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to upgrade a SP 2013 Foundation into SP 2013 Server?

If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

No, You have to Uninstall the SharePoint foundation, Then Clean Install the SharePoint 2013 server.

You can take the backup of Content DBs so that once you install the SharePoint server then you can use those.